# Using Flex to keep local SQLite database in sync with live server database

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, flex3

I want to create a Flex 3 application running in Adobe Air that accesses an SQLite database and I need to keep this database in sync with an SQL server 2005 database running a website.

Is this something that Flex supports or is it going to be a custom script? Also, has anybody done anything like this?

Edit: The synchronisation can be done on a daily basis rather than real time. The data will be read only from a front end perspective with a CMS to do updates on the website.

Answer (score 1):

LCDS has a lot of features and yes it is expensive - if you only need the offline support it is overkill. There are some tools which can be used to synchronize two databases but I do not know if they support SQLite..if not you will have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LCDS and it's offline support with Flex.

Basically it means running all your code through managed data services, which keeps the SQLite DB in sync.

Warning... LCDS is very, very expensive.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this looks to be overkill for what I need, I have edited the question to be more specific about my requirements.